# How to make aside next to content in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to web development, and I tried using flexbox for the second time, as I was doing my layout for the website I ran into an issue with floating aside. Basically, I want aside being next to content, but trying to float it, it just disappears. (all the colours are just for recognizing different elements).

**Here is an image of my layout idea:**

[image]

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 135em;
  height: 7em;
  background: rgb(68, 100, 155);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: chocolate;
  max-width: 100em;
  height: 50em;
}

aside {
  display: block;
  background: chartreuse;
  float: right;
  max-width: 20em;
  height: 50em;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: crimson;
  max-width: 135em;
  height: 22em;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section></section>
<aside></aside>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: The above layout can be made with all flex items or partial, I would say your header/footer don't need any special treatment, the content part can be done easily in flex by setting some width or not depending on your need. For better understanding how flex works, check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in a `div` and set that to `display: flex;` like this:

```
<header></header>
<div class="flex-container">
  <section></section>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container section {
  flex: 1; // By your image example it looks like you want this element to stretch
}
```